How to translate the German word "Mitmenschlich(keit)"
Both German and Dutch have two distinct words "Mitmensch" ("medemens") and "Mensch" ("mens"), and the derived adjectives "mitmenschlich" and "menschlich" (and abstract nouns derived from those). In English there is only one adjective to translate both of these: "humane". However, both the German and Dutch compounds with "mit-" ("mede-") specifically highlight the social aspect of being human "together with (others)". I'm not a native English speaker and am struggling to find a good way to translate these words (preserving the distinction, but without having to fall back on a long paraphrase). Is there some way?
In classical Chinese philosophy the word for ethics (or for the core moral values) is 仁義 (rén-yì). The first character, by itself, is often translated as "benevolence" while the second is often translated as "righteousness" (sometimes "propriety"). The translation of "benevolence" is rather awkard, in my opinion; it originates, afaik, in nineteenth century translation and suggests the stuffiness of those interpretations. In German, however, "Mitmenschlichkeit" would be a perfect modern translation.

Some characteristic usages are:

Die Kirchen riefen zu mehr Solidarität und Mitmenschlichkeit auf
Mitmenschlichkeit bedeutet auch, sich für die Schwächeren in der Gesellschaft einzusetzen
Eine mitmenschliche Gesellschaft kümmert sich um ihre Schwächsten

and

Menschlichkeit und Gerechtigkeit sind die Grundlagen einer gerechten Gesellschaft
Der Internationale Strafgerichtshof verfolgt Verbrechen gegen die Menschlichkeit
Irren ist menschlich


Thinking outside the box of literalness, neighborliness, cooperatiion, lovingkindness, everyman?

Mitmenschlich(keit) belongs to the educated register and could easily sound stuffy to listeners whose sociolect does not contain it. Those folks would more likely describe someone as korrekt, sehr freundlich, perhaps großzügig. Even wohlwollend seems a notch 'smarter' to me.

Also, "menschlich" isn't necessarily a positive quality, unlike "mitmenschlich". The German "human" is the same as English "humane", English "human" as an adjective is more like "menschlich", as in "to err is human" -> "Irren ist menschlich".

@ariola - I didn't think of that; I think "Mitmenschlichkeit" is indeed in the educated register - in official written documents or in a more philosophical context...

@SebastianRedl - I believe you're right too... Thanks for pointing this out. My post is a bit misleading in this regard.

Could you give some illuminating examples in German (or Dutch) using the words characteristically? (ie, not like "XXX is a nice sentiment").

You can actually use humanity in exactly this way, to express the human instinct to be kind to others. It is also in the word humane. Note that menschlich is more like human rather than humane.


the quality of being humane; kindness; benevolence.
— https://www.dictionary.com/browse/humanity


Alternatively, there are words like charity and mercy from a Christian tradition, but they are less of an exact match.

An alternative is humaneness — slightly less euphonious than humanity, but it avoids the ambiguity between being human and being humane.

@PLL: I agree. I suppose I choose euphony over unambiguousness here...

I think that the Dutch "medemenselijkheid" could be "compassion" in English. ("compassion" can also be "medelijden" in Dutch, "Mitleid" in German).
(I am a native speaker of Dutch)

The expression fellow man (a kindred human being) conveys a notion of empathy (ability to emotionally understand what other people feel, see things from their point of view, and imagine yourself in their place).
Example : Common courtesy and respect for one’s fellow man should always prevail.

Thanks - I've accepted the other answer as a little bit more appropriate, but I can see that "fellow man" also has similar connotations (though it's unfortunately a 'gendered' expression in contrast to the gender-neutral German terms). -- Btw just today I learned that "empathy" was only coined in 1909 (!) as translation for the German "Einfühlung" (see: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/empathy/#HisInt)

Also: https://www.etymonline.com/word/empathy

@mudskipper I didn't expect that the word empathy was so recent and its usage  growed after WW2 in journals or books related to social psychology.

Ubuntu
"Ubuntu" is imported into English from the Bantu languages, but it is in English dictionaries now, so I'll include it here:

Ubuntu (Zulu pronunciation: [ùɓúntʼù]) (meaning humanity in Bantu) describes a set of closely related Bantu African-origin value systems that emphasize the interconnectedness of individuals with their surrounding societal and physical worlds. "Ubuntu" is sometimes translated as "I am because we are" (also "I am because you are"), or "humanity towards others" (Zulu umuntu ngumuntu ngabantu). In Xhosa, the latter term is used, but is often meant in a more philosophical sense to mean "the belief in a universal bond of sharing that connects all humanity" --Wikipedia

An entry at OED says it has known uses since the mid eighteen hundreds:

The earliest known use of the noun ubuntu is in the 1860s.
OED's earliest evidence for ubuntu is from 1860, in Mission Field. --OED.com

However, according to the same Wikipedia article, "ubuntu" was apparently not well-known in English until the nineteen nineties, when it was

popularised to English-language readers through the ubuntu theology of Desmond Tutu.

Usage disclaimer:
If you are talking to the general public, be careful before assuming the word will be understood in this meaning. Ubuntu is a common Linux operating system (named that way precisely because of that meaning) and if you use ubuntu meaning humanity it is possible that even most native speakers will not know that meaning. (Thanks: @quarague). "Humaneness", as @PLL mentioned in the comments under @Cerb's answer, may be a better option for the popular audience, or at least add an explanation of "ubuntu".
I myself am a native English speaker, and first learned about this word because of Canonical's Linux OS called "Ubuntu" (about fifteen years ago, when every installation CD that they mailed out used to include a video of Nelson Mandela explaining the term). However, since then I have noticed it in social and philosophical contexts in English. I made this an answer because it is, etymologically, possibly more like the word you ask for than any Germanic or Latin-derived English word.

While the definition is correct I would be very careful before assuming the word will be understood in this meaning. Ubuntu is a common Linux operating system (presumably named that way precisely because of that meaning) and if you use ubuntu meaning humanity I would guess that even most native speakers will not know that meaning.

It might be understood by people learned in social sciences and philosophy, but I doubt the general public knows it. And only computer enthusiasts know the Linux context (and probably few of them know the origin -- I didn't).
